# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'RedrawWorkflow'

Tags: javascript

I have the following code and it works in IE but not Chrome:

```
<object id="WorkFlowGraph" name="WorkFlowGraph" width="800px" height="600px" classid="clsid:1E595677-765C-4B01-9B60-59AEE2BFAB2C" codebase="../../CAM/Scripts/WFDesigner3.ocx#Version=-1,-1,-1,-1"></object>
```

And then in Javascript:

```
document.WorkFlowGraph.NextStepID              = document.frmProcess.hidNextStepID.value;
document.WorkFlowGraph.ComponentsXML           = FixupString(document.frmProcess.hidComponentXML.value);
document.WorkFlowGraph.WorkflowXMLIn           = FixupString(document.frmProcess.hidWorkflowXML.value);
document.WorkFlowGraph.IsWorkflowAllowRevision = document.frmProcess.hidIsAllowRevision.value.toString() == 'true' ? true:false;
document.WorkFlowGraph.RedrawWorkflow();
```

I am getting an error on document.WorkFlowGraph.RedrawWorkflow();

It throws this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'RedrawWorkflow'**

I have searched and searched and can't figure it out. Please help.

Comment: Your OCX object does not expose `RedrawWorkflow()`

Comment: You should not reference elements that have an id with `document.WorkFlowGraph`. That is very bad practice. You should be using `getElementById()`

Comment: Thanks, why is it bad practice?

Comment: deprecated old way that is slow and not supported on every browser.

Comment: Active X is IE exclusive feature.  I installed IE Tab extension for Chrome and it now prompts to run.  This solves it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is an active x control...

Active X is IE exclusive feature. I installed IE Tab extension for Chrome and it now prompts to run. This solves it.